# mysqli_poll() - what's the third parameter for?

Tags: php, asynchronous, mysqli

In the absence of any documentation [beyond a function prototype](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.poll.php) I'm struggling to find what the the third parameter to the mysqli_poll() function is.

```
int mysqli_poll ( 
     array &$read , 
     array &$error , 
     array &$reject , 
     int $sec 
     [, int $usec ] )
```

Looking at the (C) source code, it appears to populate the $reject array with resources where...

```
CONN_GET_STATE((*p)->data) <= CONN_READY 
   || CONN_GET_STATE((*p)->data) == CONN_QUIT_SENT
```

Does this mean that the connection to the server is shutting down / shutdown?

Something else?

Should it be pre-poplulated with the resources to check for disconnection? Or will they be added automatically from $read and $error?

Comment: Oddly, the names of the parameters in the source differ from those in the documentation: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/mysqli/mysqli_nonapi.c#L770

Comment: Check out this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32575987/how-does-mysqli-poll-work The answers below are not quite accurate I think, but I don't understand it well enough to correct them. Posting this comment 3 years later because this is a very limited subject interest, and that thread is very useful to understand this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I built a test rig:

```
$l1 = mysqli_connect();
$l2 = mysqli_connect();
$l3 = mysqli_connect();

$s1 = "SELECT CURTIME()";
$s2 = "SELECT * FROM";   // will error #1064
$s3 = "SELECT SLEEP(10), CURTIME()";

mysqli_query($l1, $s1, MYSQLI_ASYNC);
mysqli_query($l2, $s2, MYSQLI_ASYNC);
mysqli_query($l3, $s3, MYSQLI_ASYNC);

$started=time();

for ($x=0; $x<5; $x++) {
        $ready=$reject=$errors = array($l1, $l2, $l3);
        print "\niteration $x at t+" . (time()-$started) . "\n";
        mysqli_poll($ready, $errors, $reject, 3);
        print "ready = " . count($ready) . "\n";
        foreach($ready as $r) {
           $c=mysqli_reap_async_query($r);
           print "err=" . mysqli_error($r) . " cnt=" . count($c) . "\n";
        };
        print "errors = " . count($errors) . "\n";
        print "reject = " . count($reject) . "\n";
        sleep(4);
 }
```

Results (annotations prefixed with //):

```
iteration 0 at t+0
ready = 1              // appears to be SELECT CURTIME()
err= cnt=1
errors = 0
reject = 0

iteration 1 at t+4
ready = 1              // appears to be SELECT * FROM
err=You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
  to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 
  1 cnt=1
errors = 0
reject = 1             // appears to be SELECT CURTIME() (results reaped)

iteration 2 at t+8
ready = 1              // appears to be SELECT SLEEP(10) despite 8 seconds elapsed
err= cnt=1
errors = 0
reject = 2             // appears to be SELECT CURTIME() + SELECT * FROM

iteration 3 at t+14
ready = 0
errors = 0
reject = 3

iteration 4 at t+21
ready = 0
errors = 0
reject = 3
```

i.e. $reject is getting populated with links where the results have been reaped, NOT links which are not yet ready to poll.

Trying with with an invalid connection, the value is removed from all arrays (not added to $reject),

Answer (score 3):

The arrays are bound to the select() system call.

As you see here: http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_5/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd.c#1384

So, yes, according to `select(2)` man documentation:

> Select() examines the I/O descriptor sets whose addresses are passed in readfds, writefds, and errorfds to see if some of their descriptors are ready for reading, are ready for writing, or have an exceptional condition pending, respectively.

(`writefds` is here not important, it is ignored in the implementation)

The `$read` or `$error` arrays are allowed to be empty if the other is filled with mysqli objects.

`$read` has to be an array with mysqli objects you want to *poll*.

`$error` has to be an array with mysqli objects you want to *check for extraordinary data*.

As you see from http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_5/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_enum_n_def.h#322 and http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_5/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd.c#1228, everything that doesn't match `<= CONN_READY || == CONN_QUIT_SENT` implies `CONN_QUERY_SENT, CONN_SENDING_LOAD_DATA, CONN_FETCHING_DATA, CONN_NEXT_RESULT_PENDING` (i.e. data is not yet ready to be fetched; names should be self-explaining) won't be added to the ready array == will be `$rejected`:

`$rejected` can be anything when you pass it to the function; it'll be overwritten with an array with the entries in `$read` which aren't yet ready to be read.

Comment: @symcbean hmm. noticed too late that I didn't initially fully answer the question. Had edited. But I included the other two parameters too, for Q&A, when someone else will stumble over the incomplete docs and searches for it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that's where the rejected threads end up.

> See this example:
>   https://svn.osgeo.org/mapguide/sandbox/rfc94/Oem/php/ext/mysqli/tests/mysqli_poll.phpt

Comment: What's a rejected thread? Had already seen this unit test by Ulf Wendel (Google only turns up this and all the copies of the manual page when searching for mysqli_poll)

Comment: CAn you add a blockquote?