# How does mysqli_poll work?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

The documentation on [mysqli_poll](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.poll.php) is a bit sparse.

In the example, they create 3 identical arrays containing all the MySQLi connections to check, but if you read the parameter descriptions, that doesn't look right at all.

It sounds to me like `$read` is an array holding the connections to check, but `$error` and `$reject` should be unpopulated vars that will be filled by the function if there are errors. Is that correct?

What happens when the function returns >= 1? How do you know *which* connections have data ready to be "reaped"? Is `$read` modified too? i.e. reduced to the set connections that actually have data?

Lastly, do `sec` and `usec` actually do anything? If so, what? I tried setting `sec` to `0` and `usec` to 1 (I assume that means 0 seconds + 1 microsecond = 1 microsecond total wait time) but it pauses for more than a second when I run a big query, so it doesn't seem to abort or cause an error when it times out. What does it do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**TL;DR: Your suppositions are correct, but take care in your coding.**

---

mysqli_poll is a [thin convenience wrapper around a socket select](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd.c#L1437), and knowing how [`socket_select`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-select.php) works will get you a long way toward understanding this function.

`mysqli_poll` is only available when the underlying driver is `mysqlnd`, because only MySQL ND provides native, socket-level access to the MySQL server.  The important point to keep in mind is that the "socket-level" access is what makes polling possible, and why understanding socket select is crucial in understanding the function and limitations of `mysqli_poll`.

To answer your questions:

> It sounds to me like $read is an array holding the connections to check, but $error and $reject should be unpopulated vars that will be filled by the function if there are errors. Is that correct?

Yes, but not a complete picture.  Notice the signature of `mysqli_poll`:

> int mysqli_poll ( array &$read , array &$error , array &$reject , int $sec [, int $usec ] )

All three arrays are pass-by-reference, meaning the PHP engine has the ability to modify all three, which it will.  In the obvious case, it modifies `$error` and `$reject` when any of the requested connections from `$read` are in an error or connection rejected state.

But PHP will also modify `$read` when there is data waiting to be read.  This is the key to answering your question:

> What happens when the function returns >= 1? How do you know which connections have data ready to be "reaped"? Is $read modified too? i.e. reduced to the set connections that actually have data?

Yes, and that is crucial and not obvious in the docs.  `$read` is going to get modified to the list of connections that are ready to be read.  You'll loop over them and do your business.  But an imperative point is glossed over: if `$read` is modified, what happens if you put the poll in a loop and try to read from those again?  Well, you'll only be reading from a subset, which isn't what you want.

What most examples show when doing a select in PHP is that the source `$read` array is *copied* to a new array before being select'd. In the man page for `mysqli_poll`, notice this loop that "resets" the read array just before the call to the mysqli_poll:

```
foreach ($all_links as $link) {
    $links[] = $errors[] = $reject[] = $link;
}
```

This is perhaps the most important point: each of these arrays passed into `mysqli_poll` will get modified when `mysqli_poll` finishes: the arrays will be trimmed so that only affected connections are in the result, so you have to reset the arrays each time before you call `mysqli_poll`.

Another example is seen in [this PHP note on `socket_select`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-select.php#56241).  Notice how `$read = $clients;` before the select?

To your last question:

> Lastly, do sec and usec actually do anything? If so, what? I tried setting sec to 0 and usec to 1 (I assume that means 0 seconds + 1 microsecond = 1 microsecond total wait time) but it pauses for more than a second when I run a big query, so it doesn't seem to abort or cause an error when it times out. What does it do?

Yes, it works.  These **should** represent the upper-bound PHP will wait for data to become available on any of the connections in `$read` (but read on).  <strike>It did not work for you because the *minimum* time is 1 second.  When you set `0` for second, even though you had a `> 0` microsecond, PHP interpreted that as "wait forever".</strike>

As a side note, the [unit tests for `mysqli_poll`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/mysqli/tests/mysqli_poll.phpt) might be illuminating.

---

**Update:** I wasn't near a computer to test last night.  Now that I am, I've got some observations to share.

### test 1: long running queries

```
$ cat mysqli_poll_test
$link  = mysqli_connect(...);
$sql   = 'SELECT SLEEP(2), 1';
mysqli_query($link, $sql, MYSQLI_ASYNC);

$links = array ($link);
$begin = microtime(true);
$i = 0;
do {
    printf("start i=%d @ T+%.f\n", $i, (microtime(true)-$begin));
    $read = $error = $reject = $links;
    mysqli_poll($read, $error, $reject, 1, 500000);
    printf(
        "finish i=%d, count(read, error, reject)=(%d, %d, %d) @ T+%f\n\n",
        $i++, count($read), count($error), count($reject), (microtime(true)-$begin)
    );
} while (count($links) !== count($read) + count($error) + count($reject));

$ php mysqli_poll_test
start i=0 @ T+0.000012
finish i=0, count(read, error, reject)=(0, 0, 0) @ T+1.501807

start i=1 @ T+1.501955
finish i=1, count(read, error, reject)=(1, 0, 0) @ T+2.001353
```

In this test, the long running query is a simple sleep for 2 seconds at the MySQL server.  The `mysqli_poll` has a timeout of 1.5 seconds.  As expected, after 1.5 seconds elapse, the poll returns.  Also as expected, there is no data ready to be read, so the `do .. while` restarts.  After the remaining half-second, the poll returns indicating one link is ready to read.  This is expected, because the query takes only 2 seconds to resolve and poll sees that very close to exactly two seconds.

If you change the poll timeout to half a second and re-run:

```
// changed this from 1 to 0 --------V
mysqli_poll($read, $error, $reject, 0, 500000);
```

The poll kicks out after half a second, and the loop runs four times, as expected.  If you change it to 1 microsecond as in your example, it does kick out after 1 microsecond.  And if you change it to 0 seconds and 0 microseconds, it runs as fast as it possibly can.

So, I was definitely *wrong* when I said `0` meant wait forever.

### test 2: multiple queries, some error and some long running, with timeouts

Let's change our script to have a few more links and try again:

```
$link0  = mysqli_connect(...);
$link1  = mysqli_connect(...);
$link2  = mysqli_connect(...);

$sql0   = 'SELECT SLEEP(2) AS wait, 1 AS num';
$sql1   = 'SELECT foo FROM';
$sql2   = 'SELECT 2 AS num';

mysqli_query($link0, $sql0, MYSQLI_ASYNC);
mysqli_query($link1, $sql1, MYSQLI_ASYNC);
mysqli_query($link2, $sql2, MYSQLI_ASYNC);

$links  = array ($link0, $link1, $link2);
$begin = microtime(true);
$i = 0;
do {
    printf("start i=%d @ T+%.f\n", $i, (microtime(true)-$begin));
    $read = $error = $reject = $links;
    $count = mysqli_poll($read, $error, $reject, 1, 500000);
    if (0 < $count) {
        foreach ($links as $j => $link) {
            $result = mysqli_reap_async_query($link);
            if (is_object($result)) {
                printf("link #%d, row=%s\n", $j, json_encode($result->fetch_assoc()));
                mysqli_free_result($result);
            } else if (false !== $result) {
                printf("link #%d, output=%s\n", $j, $link);
            } else {
                printf("link #%d, error=%s\n", $j, mysqli_error($link));
            }
        }
    }
    printf(
        "finish i=%d, count(read, error, reject)=(%d, %d, %d) @ T+%f\n\n",
        $i++, count($read), count($error), count($reject), (microtime(true)-$begin)
    );
} while (count($links) !== count($read) + count($error) + count($reject));
```

In this test, I'm expecting two results to resolve immediately: one a syntax error and the other a data row.  I'm also expecting this to take 1.5 seconds, since the query sleeping 2 seconds will not resolve until after the timeout expires.  That doesn't appear to be the case:

```
start i=0 @ T+0.000002
link #0, row={"wait":"0","num":"1"}
link #1, error=You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
link #2, row={"num":"2"}
finish i=0, count(read, error, reject)=(1, 0, 0) @ T+2.001756

start i=1 @ T+2.001827
finish i=1, count(read, error, reject)=(0, 0, 3) @ T+3.503024
```

It waits until the `SLEEP(2)` query resolves, violating the assertion that the timeout was the upper-bound for waiting.  The reason this happens is the `mysqli_reap_async_query`: we're iterating over all links, and each of those is being asked to be reaped.  *The reaping process waits until the query finishes.*

### test 3: long running queries with targeted reaping:

Same as test #2, but this time let's be smart about what we're reaping.

```
$ cat mysqli_poll.php
<?php
$link0  = mysqli_connect(...);
$link1  = mysqli_connect(...);
$link2  = mysqli_connect(...);

$sql0   = 'SELECT SLEEP(2) AS wait, 1 AS num';
$sql1   = 'SELECT foo FROM';
$sql2   = 'SELECT 2 AS num';

mysqli_query($link0, $sql0, MYSQLI_ASYNC);
mysqli_query($link1, $sql1, MYSQLI_ASYNC);
mysqli_query($link2, $sql2, MYSQLI_ASYNC);

$links  = array ($link0, $link1, $link2);
$begin = microtime(true);
$i = 0;
do {
    printf("start i=%d @ T+%.f\n", $i, (microtime(true)-$begin));
    $read = $error = $reject = $links;
    $count = mysqli_poll($read, $error, $reject, 1, 500000);
    printf(
        "check i=%d, count(read, error, reject)=(%d, %d, %d) @ T+%f\n",
        $i, count($read), count($error), count($reject), (microtime(true)-$begin)
    );
    if (0 < $count) {
        reap('read', $read);
        reap('error', $error);
        reap('reject', $reject);
    } else {
        printf("timeout, no results\n");
    }
    printf("finish i=%d\n\n", $i++);
} while (count($links) !== count($read) + count($error) + count($reject));

function reap($label, array $links) {
    foreach ($links as $link) {
        $result = mysqli_reap_async_query($link);
        if (is_object($result)) {
            printf("%s, row=%s\n", $label, json_encode($result->fetch_assoc()));
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        } else if (false !== $result) {
            printf("%s, output=%s\n", $label, $link);
        } else {
            printf("%s, error=%s\n", $label, mysqli_error($link));
        }
    }
}
```

And now run it.

```
$ php mysqli_poll.php
start i=0 @ T+0.000003
check i=0, count(read, error, reject)=(1, 0, 0) @ T+0.001007
read, error=You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
finish i=0

start i=1 @ T+0.001256
check i=1, count(read, error, reject)=(1, 0, 1) @ T+0.001327
read, row={"num":"2"}
reject, error=You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
finish i=1

start i=2 @ T+0.001627
check i=2, count(read, error, reject)=(0, 0, 2) @ T+1.503261
timeout, no results
finish i=2

start i=3 @ T+1.503564
check i=3, count(read, error, reject)=(1, 0, 2) @ T+2.001390
read, row={"wait":"0","num":"1"}
reject, error=You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
reject, error=
finish i=3
```

Much better.  Each query resolves in its own good time, with appropriate arrays filled out.  The important difference in this example, versus earlier is that *we iterate over each of the modified arrays*.  This runs contrary to some documentation, which shows iterating over all the links themselves.

I've opened [documentation bug #70505](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=70505) on it.

Comment: Reading the description of `socket_select`, `0` does *not* main "wait forever", it means "return immediately"; `null` means "block indefinitely". Does `mysqli_poll` behave differently? Or perhaps there was an error in my implementation. Regardless, thank you -- this is quite helpful.

Comment: @Mark Yep, you're right: my memory was wrong. I've run some tests and expanded my answer.

Comment: Wow, you rock :D How'd you get a read count of 1 though, in test #2? I ran the same code and got 2 which makes more sense because both link #0 and link #2 have data to be read. It did wait just over 2 seconds though.

Comment: @Mark: Don't know, I wondered the same thing. I was expecting `(1,1,0) @ T+1.5`, but when it came out wrong on the timing I decided to focus on that.  I have sneaking suspicion that the timing affecting bugs also affects the array filling, but I haven't trudged the code yet.  If they turn out to be different, I'll open another bug.  BTW, on what OS and PHP version did you get a read count of 2?  My results are on `Linux 3.14.27-25.47.amzn1.x86_64` running 5.6.13.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.10 (3.16.0-37-generic). I think you have a bug in your test #2. `mysqli_poll` *is* returning before the 1.5s are up, but you're reaping the result of the sleeper query even though poll hasn't said its ready -- that's where all the time is taken.

Comment: @Mark: Right!  I've fixed that locally and updated my post.  The results are better now.

Comment: I know it is taboo to say thanks in the comments, but this is not a very active topic anywhere, so I'm breaking the laws and saying Thank You Biship!! This really helped me understand the nuances of mysqli_poll and the entire process, where the docs were useless. Much appreciated.

Comment: I really liked your explanation, but your tests are slightly confusing. Was the typo in test #2 intentional? Why `foreach ($links as $j => $link)` instead of `foreach ($read as $j => $link)` as the manual suggests? IMO this defeats the purpose of `mysqli_poll` since the `mysqli_reap_async_query()` has to wait for all links and then execute poll again.

Comment: What is the point of `printf("link #%d, output=%s\n", $j, $link);`? You can't convert mysqli object into a string. Is this also a typo?

Comment: Could you explain the third test please? What do you mean by targeted reaping? Why do you reap from each link?

Comment: @Dharman The manual is wrong (I say that with love, being a php.net engine developer): we loop over $links because any that are in error will not be in $read. The printf are all diagnostic, and every object in PHP has a string representation, regardless of a toString magic method: in this case the string is the object ID which is unique amongst the links.

Comment: I was actually getting " Uncaught Error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string"

Comment: @Dharman What version of PHP? And what mysql driver? Targeted reaping means "only operate on those needing attention".

Comment: I am testing this on PHP 8.0, but as far as I know mysqli never had string representation. I am doing some regression testing and trying to fix a bug.

Comment: Ah, 8.0. Many core changes in that, incl to internal classes. The simple fix to the conversion error is to use spl_object_id around the object to get a string ID.