# Why we use mysqli_poll() function in php?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am totally new to php and mysql. Please can anyone tell why we use **mysqli_poll()** function in php ?

I found 2 questions on stack overflow:
1) [How does mysqli_poll work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32575987/how-does-mysqli-poll-work)
2) [mysqli_poll() - what's the third parameter for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17892673/mysqli-poll-whats-the-third-parameter-for)

But both are different from my question. In fact i have read them but unable to understand.

Currently i am on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.poll.php) for this function and trying to understand the examples but i am too much depressed and failed to understand.

Please can anyone tell me in easy and beginners level, that what is the use of this function in php and mysql. What is means by poll in the sense of mysql database ?

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: If you don't know what it is or does at all even after reading documentation, then you probably don't need it.

Comment: It's for asynchronous queries, which are not something you're likely to need as a beginner. Ignore it. Shame that the docs for mysqli suck as much as they do, but the same goes for mysqli itself. PDO > \*

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton- This is not the answer to my question.

Comment: @Sammitch-Thank you for your short answer. I respect you. You mean those queries which does not block other called async. Can you please do a simple example that looks like a nice tutorial for beginner.

Comment: @StressedBrain: why is the answer not okay? Why do you think that you need this method? I have never heard of it, and I'm working with PHP and MySQL every day

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton-Please if you don't have the answer, keep doing your own work.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton-Basically i am learning all the mysql functions. Tomorrow is test in the academy and that is the last function i need to understand. Rest of the functions are done. This one is left.

Comment: I did research on it and didn't find any useful resource and trust me i did practice on it but nothing is happening. If i share my practice source code here i hope i will get negative marking. Please i request you if you know what this function is used for then please provide the answer in easy words. I will understand it, its upon me then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling this is a wrapper around a POSIX-style [`select`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_(Unix)) call, or something similar in nature, that's used to efficiently poll multiple handles for data that can be read.

Normally `select`-driven code is deemed to be "polling" when it checks for data ready to be read or handles ready to be written to.

It's unlikely that most programmers have ever used this function. It has very narrow use cases, you must be juggling a non-trivial number of MySQL handles at once. Most applications use a handful, and often with a connection pool.

Comment: If i understand the word **poll** or **polling** in the sense of mysql database then it means i understand the answer as well as this function. Please can you tell me what is meant by **poll/polling** in the sense of mysql database ?

Comment: It's a general term that means to check if there's anything that needs to be done. Within the context of a database it might mean that query results have come through. This could, theoretically, allow you to asynchronously call multiple queries and process them as they return results, not necessarily blocking for each one.